# Unable to connect to Impala through AWS Lambda using Ibis

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, impala, ibis

I have an AWS Lambda function written in python2.7. Using the lambda function I am trying to connect to Impala (installed on an ec2 instance). The py lambda function uses Ibis to connect to Impala.

While trying to test from Lambda, I get the below error:

```
"errorType": "TTransportException",
"errorMessage": "Could not connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:21050"
```

Code:

```
hdfs = ibis.hdfs_connect(host=db_cfg["hdfs_host"], port=db_cfg["hdfs_port"], user=db_cfg["hdfs_user"])
        client = ibis.impala.connect(host=db_cfg["impala_host"], port=db_cfg["impala_port"], hdfs_client=hdfs)
```

Is this not possible through AWS Lambda?

Comment: Did you configure the security groups to allow access on that port?

Comment: Yes... I tried to connect to Impala from another ec2 instance and that worked

Comment: Lambdas are in a different VPC than your EC2 instances

Comment: I've added VPC's to the Lambda function. I get the same error

Comment: It worked on replacing the host IP with the full DNS : ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-1a.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the security group configured properly - the port needs to be open on the private interface not to the internet.